# Why runtime error occurs when 10 user concurrent request the same page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, concurrency

This page I use crystal report to generate a report, but if 10 user or more request this page at the same time, some of the user will get a runtime error.

But if normal use, everything is all right.

Sample code:

```
                report.Load(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "reports\\test.rpt");
            report.FileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "reports\\test.rpt";

            report.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ReportServer, Properties.Settings.Default.ReportDatabase, Properties.Settings.Default.ReportUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.ReportPassword);
            report.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "Countries");
```

Comment: What OS are you running on?  Client versions of Windows have a limitation of 10 simultaneous connections.

Comment: I am using Windows, both server and client. do you mean if the request exceed 10, then will get a runtime error but not a message to prompt you the number of request reach the limit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably hosting the report on a consumer-level edition of Windows, such as XP or Vista.

Consumer-level Windows editions will not accept more than ten concurrent inbound connections.

You need to use Windows Server.

Comment: No, it was deployed to client, so the server is windows server 2003 version.